# Magento 2 CSS button appearance wrong on mobile browsers

Tags: magento2, css, mobile

Mobile version:
[image]

PC/Ipad tablet version:
[image]

Any clue why mobile iOS/android version dosn't match with pc version/ipad/tablet version? What could be the cause?

Comment: We need more information as this could be a number of things. Browser cache, unsupported CSS, difference in how browsers handle certain CSS properties. Can you share your CSS for this please and confirm if you have flushed browser cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I had to add full path with div classes and element ol in css on all related codes. :))